# rails f.number_field vs number_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hash, form-for

I'm working on this form, trying to populate my values Hash and send it via params to my controller:

```
<%= form_for(cash_count) do |f| %>
   ....
   <%= f.label "200 bills", :class => "input-group-addon" %>
   <%= number_field_tag "vals[b200]", :class => "form-control" %>
```

If I understand correctly, number_field_tag sends the field result pair in **params** (works fine), and f.number_field sends the field result pair in **params.cash_count** (can't make it work).

I can't do it with **f.number_field** though.

I'm trying

```
<%= f.number_field 'vals["b200"]', :class => "form-control" %>
```

and I get

```
undefined method `vals["b200"]' for #<CashCount:0x007f371a756068>
```

Altough in irb this syntax seems to be right:

```
2.4.0 :028 > d = CashCount.new 

2.4.0 :029 > d.vals = c.vals

2.4.0 :031 > d.vals
 => {"b200"=>"3"} 

2.4.0 :033 > d.vals["b200"]
 => "3"
```

CLARIFICATION: I've posted this question at first with the "vals" column in another name - "values". I encountered some problems because it is similar to the Hash.values method, so I've changed it to "vals".

Comment: What the type of column `values` ?

Comment: t.text     "values"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `value` param to prepopulate input values

```
<%= f.number_field :my_attribute, value: f.object.values['b200'], class: '...' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work if you really want to use number_field instead of number_field_tag, Internally the implementation of these helpers are slightly different

```
<%= form_for(cash_count) do |f| %>
    ....
    <%= f.label "200 bills", :class => "input-group-addon" %>
    <%= f.fields_for :values do |n|%>
        <%= n.number_field :b200 , :class => "form-control" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

which gives output like

```
"cash_count" => {"values" => {"b200" => "3"}}
```

Comment: Thanks! It does pass through to the controller now in the right way (I think), my cash_count_params is this:

`code`"cash_count"=><ActionController::Parameters {"cash_drawer_id"=>"1", "expected_total"=>"111", "values"=><ActionController::Parameters {"b200"=>"2"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>`code`

BUT - the "values" parameters still isn't saved to the database, should I take the hash key-value pairs manually and build the values Hash manually?

Comment: Glad that help.

Comment: I am not sure about the model associations and the strong parameters configuration in the controller.Try to debug using any tools like pry and see what are the errors.

Comment: Ok, I've succeeded saving and retrieving the cash_count object. After I load it for edit it looks like this:---  #<CashCount id: 90, cashier: "yonyossef2", count_date: "2019-02-27", count_time: "2000-01-01 14:00:00", expected_total: 2.0, counted_total: nil, cash_drawer_id: 1, created_at: "2019-02-27 12:36:07", updated_at: "2019-02-27 12:36:07", user_id: 2, vals: {"b200"=>"3", "b100"=>"4"},......     PROBLEM: my form doesn't show vals current values on edit (the form input was implemented as you suggested). Rest of the inputs are fine
---
Any ideas why? Or better, how do I debug such problem?

Comment: If my understanding is correct vals is a column with hash values in the CashCount table with a hash. In that either you need to loop and show values(no default mechanism) from the hash unless there is an association between two.